# Add time to setInterval on click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval

I'm using the following code to run a function every 30 seconds. How can I reset/restart the setInterval if the user clicks the mouse, with js/jQuery? So if the user clicks during the 30 seconds, 30 new seconds will start until next click etc.

```
setInterval(function(){
    // Stuff
}, 30000);
```

Comment: [Detecting idle time in JavaScript elegantly](//stackoverflow.com/q/667555), [Detecting user inactivity over a browser - purely through javascript](//stackoverflow.com/q/13246378), [How to know browser idle time?](//stackoverflow.com/q/9564602)

Answer (score 4):

You'll have to clear the old interval, and start a new one

```
var i = setInterval(function(){
    // Stuff
}, 30000);

element.onclick = function() {
    clearInterval(i);
    i = setInterval(function(){
        // Stuff
    }, 30000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to clear the interval.

```
clearInterval(i);
```